# Orbeon Forms Properties File

Tags: properties, orbeon

I have placed the properties-local file for Orbeon form is the location `\webapps\orbeon\WEB-INF\resources\config\properties-local.xml` location. But when my tomcat starts the log shows that it uses property file as follows `config/properties-prod.xml`(Please see the image attached). So the changes I make in properties-local.xml do not get reflected, could you please advice where to make the settings which property file Orbeon should use.[image: Tomcat log]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for [`properties-prod.xml`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/e00f9f8bd56fc2a045ffa052e3d99bda75e97b87/src/main/resources/config/properties-prod.xml) as of Orbeon Forms 2017.1, you will see that it includes `properties-local.xml`. This means that your statement:

> So the changes I make in `properties-local.xml` do not get reflected

does not logically follow. There must be another reason why your changes are not taken into account.